# Kentico sync 404 error on large files

Tags: kentico

I have some large video files that are causing a 404 sync error. I know it's due to the size. I've done some digging and found this great article: http://www.mcbeev.com/Blog/September-2012/Kentico-CMS-Quick-Tip-Content-Staging-and-Large-Files

My media library is in /kff/media with the appropriate subfolders for the media libraries.

I have added the following to my web.config. Right now, my biggest file is around 90meg, but i'm expecting larger video files. But i'm still getting errors.

```html
  <!-- Sales Force Resourse Site Start -->
  <location path="KFF/media">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="2400" maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648"/>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <!-- Sales Force Resourse Site End -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your main web.config for this, not a web.config in the media directory.

You'd set your `maxRequestLength` = 100000.  I should mention the default value of 2097152 is over 2GB so you should be fine.  Or you can [use a simple converter](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=kb%20to%20mb) to do the work.

Comment: Here's where i'm getting confused. The first system.web block has the httpRunTime maxRequestLength at 2097151, which i thought would be enough.
`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" waitChangeNotification="1" maxWaitChangeNotification="3600" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxUrlLength="1000"/>`

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, are these values in the main web.config?  By the looks of you're question, it appears this might be in a different directory OR you have this as another node in your main web.config.  I'd suggest making the change globally for the site before you try to get to a specific smaller change.

Comment: I was in the web.config in root. I didn't do a nested .config file. I'm going to get back to this later today. It's not mission critical at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem a few days back and this is what I exactly did to resolve the problem at hand. The Following link and a screen shot will help you

[Staging Large files](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Staging+large+files)

Screen shot helping explain everything clearly.
[image]

Also on your project web.config file you need to check that you are not limited by how big files you can stage using Kentico staging. This parameter will override whatever settings you have in terms of files size restriction.

```
<add key="CMSMediaFileMaxStagingSize" value="102400" />
```

> You can also configure the limits on the source server by setting the
>   maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength attributes inside the
>   main  and  sections of the web.config
>   (NOT within a specific  section). This affects all types of
>   requests, not just the staging service.